# How to implement wall collision when walls are one group and my sprites are in another

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a game where a player moves through a level, the target moves randomly through the level and there are guards (not part of game yet). I am having trouble implementing a wall collision as my sprites are circles and my walls are rectangles so I do not know how to do this also, the walls and the sprites are in different classes and groups.

I've thought about using masks for my sprites but I am not confident with how to do this. I also don't know how to design the method for wall collisions as the current one sends my player (I have not got it working for the target as well) to the bottom of any wall.

```
class characters(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, colour, width, height):
        super().__init__()
        self.colour = colour
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.image = pygame.Surface([self.width, self.height])
        self.image.fill(white)
        self.image.set_colorkey(white)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect() 
        pygame.draw.circle(self.image, self.colour, [int(self.width/2), int(self.height/2)], int(self.width/2))

    def moveRight(self, pixels):
        self.rect.x += pixels

    def moveLeft(self, pixels):
        self.rect.x -= pixels

    def moveUp(self, pixels):
        self.rect.y -= pixels

    def moveDown(self, pixels):
        self.rect.y += pixels

    def moveRandom(self, pixels, clockrate, count, xdirection, ydirection):
        self.rect.x += pixels * xdirection
        self.rect.y += pixels * ydirection
        #print(self.rect.x,self.rect.y)

    def wallCollide(self):
        x = self.rect.x
        for xpos in [-5,5]:
            self.rect.x += xpos
            if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, wallSet, False, pygame.sprite.collide_rect):
                self.rect.x -= xpos
            else:
                self.rect.x = x
        y = self.rect.y
        for ypos in [-5,5]:
            self.rect.y += ypos
            if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, wallSet, False, pygame.sprite.collide_rect):
                self.rect.y -= ypos
            else:
                self.rect.y = y
```

I attempted a mask in the wall class below, don't think it works.

```
class walls(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        super().__init__()
        self.width  = width
        self.height = height
        self.x      = x
        self.y      = y

        self.image = pygame.Surface([width,height])
        self.image.fill(black)
        #self.image.set_colorkey(black) Using this will make the walls invisible as I have textured walls drawn over
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=(self.x, self.y))
        pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)
```

I have only given one wall and reduced the resolution as it is far easier whilst I write my code. The resolution should be 1920 by 1080. Use 600 by 650 to see the two walls.

```
characterSet = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = characters(black, 30, 30)
target = characters(green, 30, 30)
characterSet.add(player, target)

wallSet = pygame.sprite.Group()
Wall1 = walls(288,176, 200,142)
Wall2 = walls(286,427, 201,140)
wallSet.add(Wall1,Wall2)
```

The main game loop

```
while not end:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            end = True

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        player.moveLeft(5)
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        player.moveRight(5)
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        player.moveUp(5)
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        player.moveDown(5)

    if count%clockrate == 0:
        xdirection = random.choice(direction)
        ydirection = random.choice(direction)
    target.moveRandom(2, clockrate, count, xdirection, ydirection)
    count += 1

    if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, wallSet, False, pygame.sprite.collide_rect):
        player.wallCollide()
    gameDisplay.blit(level1,[0,0])
    wallSet.draw(gameDisplay)
    gameDisplay.blit(innerWalls,[0,0])
    characterSet.draw(gameDisplay)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you have a list of wall objects and a list of character objects and you want to check collision between all of them. this can be accomplished quickly by looping over both lists:

```
for wall in WallSet:
    for character in CharacterSet:
        character.checkCollision(wall)
```

The `checkCollision()` method can be very simple, checking if the rectangles around your objects overlap would just be a few if statements.  If you want this `checkCollisions()` method to work well for rounded characters you'll need to write something fancier.  I would suggest:

1. Write a function that will give the point inside a rectangle that is closest to another point (the hard part! Though I'm sure there are tutorials on how to do this online)
2. Take that point inside the wall's rectangle, and check if that is far enough away from the character's middle position to not be colliding.

Hopefully this helps! For future questions I would suggest trying to very clearly ask 1 question and reduce the code you are posting further.  For the question you are asking, the amount of code you posted is too much, and probably turned away potential answerers for these past 2 days.

Comment: Thanks Hoog, I wasn't even sure where to start with fixing this collision problem I have so I posted the collision part inside the game loop and the two classes which was far too much. And I kept changing my question as I kept fixing little parts of it but it was still not working so the question ended up being very ambigious. My next question will be far better I hope, thank you again.